# Check if variable is React node or array

Tags: javascript, properties, reactjs

I'd like to have a condition that states if a prop is a React node then just place it as a child within a component, and if it's not, take some action to make it into a component.
This way my component will be able to accept this prop as an array of strings, or an array of nodes.

I tried to check if `React.PropTypes.node` would return a boolean but it doesn't work.

Say I have a module called `List` and there's a prop called `items`. I'd like to be able to pass

```
var items = [
  "One",
  "Two",
  "Three"
]
```

as well as

```
var items = function () {
  return (
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  )
}
```

And within the component have some logic that would detect the difference and if it's a plain array (not an array of nodes) be able to map the items.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

React has a function just to check if a variable is an element, here's the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement).

```
React.isValidElement(obj)
```

Comment: Be aware that while `null` is valid as a React no-op, `isValidElement` returns `false`. So you will need to check for that separately.

Comment: Note the distinction between an Element and Component.

Comment: Not only null — see [Caveats](https://react.dev/reference/react/isValidElement#caveats) in isValidElement docs about distinction between _node_ and _element_.